# "@" for tensor multiplication using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

This article https://towardsdatascience.com/understand-kaiming-initialization-and-implementation-detail-in-pytorch-f7aa967e9138 about intelligent weights initialization uses the syntax

```
x@w
```

to signify tensor (/matrix) multiplication.  I had not seen that before and instead had presumed we would need to "spell it out" as :

```
 torch.mm(x, w.t())
```

What is required to use the former (nicer) syntax? That article did not show a complete set of the imports they were using.

Comment: [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) -- A dedicated infix operator for matrix multiplication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Python 3.5 and above can use this "@" syntax. The following are equivalent:

```py
a = torch.rand(2,2)
b = torch.rand(2,2)

c = a.mm(b)
print(c)

c = torch.mm(a, b)
print(c)

c = torch.matmul(a, b)
print(c)

c = a @ b # python > 3.5+
print(c)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0.2675, 0.8140],
        [0.0415, 0.1644]])
tensor([[0.2675, 0.8140],
        [0.0415, 0.1644]])
tensor([[0.2675, 0.8140],
        [0.0415, 0.1644]])
tensor([[0.2675, 0.8140],
        [0.0415, 0.1644]])
```

I like to use `mm` syntax for matrix to matrix multiplication and `mv` for matrix to vector multiplication.

To get the transposed matrix I like to use easy `a.T` syntax.

One more thing to add:

```
a = torch.rand(2,2,2)
b = torch.rand(2,2,2)

c = torch.matmul(a, b)
print(c)

c = a @ b # python > 3.5+
print(c)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[0.2951, 0.3021],
         [0.8663, 1.0430]],

        [[0.2674, 1.3792],
         [0.0895, 0.9703]]])
tensor([[[0.2951, 0.3021],
         [0.8663, 1.0430]],

        [[0.2674, 1.3792],
         [0.0895, 0.9703]]])
```

`mm` cannot work for rank>2 (tensor of rank 3 or more). So if you work with bigger ranks use just these: `matmul` or `@` notation.

Comment: Thanks for laying this all out. `numpy` and now `pytorch` are the only parts of python (well it's ecosystem in any case) that I like - but they _are_ _very_ good.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't require anything as such. Just `import torch` is enough (and the two operands must be tensors). For example, I tried

```
import torch
a = torch.randn((2, 2)) # tensor([[-0.3023, -1.3499], [-2.5096, -0.8977]])
b = torch.randn((2, 3)) # tensor([[-1.3319,  2.2378, -0.1892], [-0.3895, -0.5334, -0.5148]])
a@b
```

and the result was

```
tensor([[ 0.9284,  0.0436,  0.7521],
        [ 3.6921, -5.1372,  0.9370]])
```

and to verify, I also did

```
torch.matmul(a, b)
```

and the result was same as before

```
tensor([[ 0.9284,  0.0436,  0.7521],
        [ 3.6921, -5.1372,  0.9370]])
```

Another thing to note is that NumPy also has the same @ operator for matrix multiplication (and PyTorch have usually tried to replicate similar behaviour with tensors as NumPy does for it's arrays).

Comment: Thanks for that input: also that `numpy` has similar support